# Nginx/Wordpress - How to write: if URL has query string (?) do not 404

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404, query-string

Okay so my site is running on Nginx/Wordpress

If I navigate to: **http://www.website.com/page-one/** - the page works, great.

If I navigate to: **http://www.website.com/page-one?mm_campaign=ew328r9283rj293rj239**

**FYI:** *This error is caused with **or** without the trailing slash `/` at the end of the URL*

I get a 404 error and am redirected to the home page because it thinks that page doesn't exist.

So, I know the 404 to the home page is because of this:

```
            error_page 404 @foobar;

    location @foobar {
            rewrite  .*  / permanent;
            }
```

If I take that out, then I get a the generic 404 Nginx error page, which I definitely don't want.

I need to be able to use the URLs with query strings in order to track certain things. I basically need it to not 404 if the URL has a query string. I need to somehow write, **if the URL has a query string, do not 404, go to the URL up until the query string starts...but keep the query string so I can track you...**

I just don't know how to write that. I'm not even sure I'm writing it correctly in plain English. Sigh.

Help please!

Comment: Have this exact issue, was a solution ever found?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress permalinks enforce the trailing `/` on urls.

So the canonical URL is `http://www.website.com/page-one/`

WordPress automatically 301 redirects `http://www.website.com/page-one` to `http://www.website.com/page-one/`

Your query string is not appended to the canonical url, it's appended to the redirected URL, which confuses WordPress and causes it to 404.

If you change `http://www.website.com/page-one?mm_campaign=ew328r9283rj293rj239` to `http://www.website.com/page-one/?mm_campaign=ew328r9283rj293rj239` it should work.